# How to specialize a components of JavaFX and hide its API to only show mine

Tags: java, javafx-2

As said in the title I want to specialize the usage of a TableView that I will reuse many time, that speciazation contains :

- Columns shown
- Filtering of what is added according to a default duplicate filter and some addiotional (either based on boolean values or callbacks).

I use raw FXML files and Controller, no UI drag and drop building.

In order to keep the usage of my component the easiest possible I would like to hide the component part of JavaFX and only allow my methods, how to do it ?

Comment: Looks like you want to apply a [facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), but I guess you already know that.  The link contains abstract information on the pattern but not specific information for appealing it for your use case.  A [bridge pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) could also be applied here, though it is slightly different and probably overly abstracts for your needs.

Comment: @jewelsea yes the problem is the constraint imposed by JavaFX that I have to inherit from their component to create a new graphic component but seems like fabian came with a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class extending `Control`. Add the methods you want the user to access to this class.

Create a skin for this class and implement the behavior you don't want the user to access there.

Benefits:

- Hides the implementation details from user.
- Allows the user to replace the "private" behavior, if neccessary.
- Allows you to access the "public" behavior form the node directly.

### Example

#### Control

```
public class MyControl extends Control {

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new MyControlSkin(this);
    }

    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final String getText() {
        return this.text.get();
    }

    public final void setText(String value) {
        this.text.set(value);
    }

    public final StringProperty textProperty() {
        return this.text;
    }

}
```

#### Skin

```
public class MyControlSkin extends SkinBase<MyControl> {

    public MyControlSkin(MyControl control) {
        super(control);

        Text text = new Text();
        text.textProperty().bind(control.textProperty());

        getChildren().setAll(text);
    }

}
```

#### Use

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final MyControl control = new MyControl();
    Button btn = new Button("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        control.setText("Hello World!");
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(10, btn, control));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

Note that it does not matter how you create the UI. It could be directly created from java or loaded from fxml - this does not matter. You could e.g. use the skin as fxml controller and root:

```xml
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.control.SkinBase" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <Text fx:id="text"/>
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

```
@FXML
private Text text;

public MyControlSkin(MyControl control) throws IOException {
    super(control);
    getChildren().clear();

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(someUrl);
    loader.setRoot(this);
    loader.setController(this);
    loader.load();

    text.textProperty().bind(control.textProperty());
}
```

---

BTW: The duplicate filtering would IMHO be better of in a seperate class, like a `TransformationList`. This way you could reuse the behavior independent of the UI which would allow easier reuse (e.g. For use with a `ListView`).

Comment: This is the solution if you want to create skinnable and thus highly reusable controls. For application developers, though, the solution provided by Walfrat is often enough.

Comment: @Walfrat read the wiki page on the [UI Controls Architecture](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/UI+Controls+Architecture) to better understand the concept of the skin thing.  It is a kind of bridge pattern allowing you to swap in and out different look and feels and behaviors for a control (by changing skin implementations) without changing the API for the control.  For example a date time picker might have a mobile skin which acts like a touchscreen rolodex and a desktop skin which uses a drop down combo box, but the control API remains the same.

Comment: To be honest I am not a huge fan, just inheriting from the class Control give me 50 methods inherited. I think I'm gonna go with your way while keeping the interface of my solution.

Comment: Sidenote : if you use the skin constructor to pass more parameters, and need to copy the reference into your skin (`this.a=a`), don't forget to do it before calling the load() method, or it won't work ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the current way I found to do it  use an interface an use that interface when using `@FXML` injection.

My specialized components :

```
public class EquipmentTableView extends AnchorPane implements IEquipmentTableView{[...]}
```

Where `AnchorPane` is from `JavaFX` and the interface from me.

The FXML of the component :

```xml
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <TableView fx:id="tableView"
        AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
        AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">

    </TableView>
</fx:root>
```

The FXML to include the component :

```xml
<EquipmentTableView fx:id="tableView"/>
```

The injection in the controller

```
public class ReadController {  
        // use the interface here 
        @FXML private IEquipmentTableView tableView;

        public static String FXML="read.fxml";
        public static String TITLE_KEY="read.title";

        @FXML
        void initialize(){
            tableView.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                    new Equipment("name1", "partNumber1", "MFC1", "00000000001", "3400000000000001"),
                    new Equipment("name2", "partNumber2", "MFC2", "00000000002", "3400000000000002"),
                    new Equipment("name3", "partNumber3", "MFC3", "00000000003", "3400000000000003")));
        }
}
```

To sum it up :

- By using the `TableView` inside the components instead of inheriting it I don't allow to manipulate the `TableView`. I inherit AnchorPane instead because I want my table view to auto-resize, you can inherits from Pane otherwise.
- I am allowed to manipulate it using only the interface methods since I cannot access the TableView.
- Using only the interface disallow myself to manipulate the AnchorPane for other purposes or having to search through the methods that are mines.

Comment: +1 and for simplicity and if you bother that much to have some additional methods from the inherited pane you could omit the interface (IEquipmentTableView).

Comment: I wanted to push my solution as far as possible and I didn't expected the injection to work, I just thought for a second "let's try like Spring".